# Usar DNI/CUIL como clave primaria en SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Estoy por desarrollar un software en **JAVA** con **SQL** o **mySQL** que tenga varias tablas y demás con clientes. Y quería saber que tan recomendable es utilizar el **CUIL** o el **DNI** como clave primaria. Antes que un **ID** autoincrementable.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: yo dejaría el autoincremental, y sobre la columna dni/cuil creo un índice